# Jquery show div content onload and hide of the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a side menu bar that menu items has id's `'h1-1', 'h1-2','h1-3'` and so on.  when first load the page I need to show the `'h1-1'` content. so I've written code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {   
        window.onload = $('#h1-1').show();
    });
```

But here, when I click other menu item first, `'h1-1'` content is still show on the page and clicked list item content showing below the `'h1-1'` content .

However when I `'h1-1'` itself first and then click other list items, it works fine (when I `'h1-1'` itself first, `'h1-1'` content still showing and then click other list item `'h1-1'` content go away and show clicked item content).

I've tried to write hide the `'h1-1'` content on the first click but then, `'h1-1'` content is not showing even when click the `'h1-1'` list item itself.

Can anyone suggest a way how can I solve this..

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M3ZhV/452/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relying on the content of `curPage` to hide the previous page, but you initialize it to "". Instead, set it to the first page.

```
var curPage="h1-1";
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M3ZhV/458/)

Answer (score 1):

try this... all the codes are there.. I just updated your code.

```
$(function() {
var curPage="";
$("#menu a").click(function() {
    $('#h1-1').hide();
    if (curPage.length) { 

        $("#"+curPage).hide();
    }
    curPage=$(this).data("page");
    $("#"+curPage).show();
});
});

 $(document).ready(function() {   
    window.onload = $('#h1-1').show();
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M3ZhV/454/

Comment: all you need is to hide that when you click the menus.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are complicating the things. Use a selector to get all elements to hide ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/M3ZhV/456/)).

```
$(function() {
    $('#h1-1').show();
    $("#menu a").click(function() {
        var curPage = $(this).data("page");
        $('.main div.content').hide();
        $("#" + curPage).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change var curPage=""; to var curPage="h1-1";

```
$(function() {
    var curPage="h1-1";
    $("#menu a").click(function() {
        if (curPage.length) { 
            $("#"+curPage).hide();
        }
        curPage=$(this).data("page");
        $("#"+curPage).show();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {   
    window.onload = $('#h1-1').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M3ZhV/457/